FDTD boundary condition that replicates an infinitely thin mirror
I'm currently running a 1-D FDTD simulation where I want to model a dielectric mirror (with an anti-reflection coating on one side but let's keep it simple for now). For my purposes, the mirror can be considered infinitely thin, and so I was looking for boundary conditions that can replicate this. It's essentially Fresnel reflections but with both sides having the same refractive index. I've looked around to no avail. Does such a boundary condition exist and if so, how is it implemented?
Edit: I've added the following equations for clarification. I'm assuming vacuum in all spaces within the grid. The update equations for the electric and magnetic fields, assuming a Yee grid, are
$E_y|_{t+\Delta t}^{z}=E_y|_{t}^{z}+\frac{c_0\Delta t}{\Delta z}({H_x|_{t+{\Delta t/2}}^{z}-H_x|_{t+{\Delta t/2}}^{z-1}})$
$H_x|_{t+\Delta t/2}^{z}=H_x|_{t-\Delta t/2}^{z}+\frac{c_0\Delta t}{\Delta z}({E_y|_{t}^{z+1}-E_y|_{t}^{z}})$
where $\Delta t$ and $\Delta z$ are the time and spatial steps. The electric field at any point is given by a superposition of two counter-propagating waves, i.e.
$E_y=Asin(\omega t+kz)+Bsin(\omega t-kz)$
where A and B are arbitrary real constants.
I was wondering if a boundary condition exists that could replicate Fresnel reflections. Fresnel reflections, for a single propagating plane wave, results in
$E_y=tE_f+rE_b$
where $E_f$ and $E_b$ are the forward and backward propagating modes. $r$ and $t$ are arbitrary real constants and need only obey
$|r|^2+|t|^2=1$

What is the partial differential equation you are looking for boundary conditions for?

I'm using the standard 1D FDTD equations with a Yee grid. See p.8 of these slides here [https://empossible.net/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/Lecture-Review-Walkthrough-of-1D-FDTD.pdf].

That's a discretization, but I was asking for the equations you are trying to discretize.

Ah alright. For now it's two counter-propagating plane waves.

I suggest that you write the differential equation and boundary conditions mathematically. That way it might be easier to help you.

I've edited my post. Please see the new equations.

It would be more informative to have the differential equations and boundary conditions. What you are showing us is not a boundary condition but a consequence of it. If I understand correctly, you want to model is a vacuum followed by an infinitely thin sheet with a different permittivity and vacuum after that as well

I think the boundary condition is E_y(z) = r * E_b(z), since E_f is the field beyond the boundary. I want to model a vacuum followed by an infinitely thin sheet (mirror) followed by vacuum. If the sheet was fully transparent then there would be no reflection. I'd like that sheet to function as a mirror so there would be some reflection.

I don't think so. The boundary conditions in your case would be the continuity of the fields between media. Furthermore, numerically you can't have an infinitely thin slab there, you need to add one with a finite thickness. Using another method, such as transfer matrix method might be a better fit for your problem
